# Chrome developer tools show mac address but not ip address, how to get ip address

Tags: command-line, google-chrome

I wanted to get apps ip address but getting mac address in the chrome developer tool. What change will help to get the IP address instead of max address. I don't see IP address in ipconfig command response too. pls help to get it.

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 3):

This isn’t a MAC address. It’s an [IPv6](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IPv6) address. You couldn’t communicate using a MAC address on the internet, because they’re not routable.

If you want to find the IPv4 of *example.com*, use `nslookup` or similar tools:

```
% host example.com
example.com has address 93.184.216.34
example.com has IPv6 address 2606:2800:220:1:248:1893:25c8:1946
```